# Websocket with FastAPI in Render

Tags: python, websocket, deployment

I have this backend in python deployed in Render, and it just consists of a simple websocket that users need to connect to, but it always fails to connect.

The thing is that whenever I try to connect to it (via `wss://<direction>:10000/`) it ends up failing to connect every single time, I've launched uvicorn with `--host 0.0.0.0` and `--port 10000` so I don't understand what the issue is here, any ideas?

**Edit**: I now notice it may be because I always get a

```
('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 0) - "WebSocket /%xxx/" 403
INFO:     connection rejected (403 Forbidden)
```

Which I guess means it is making the connection fail, could this be caused because of CORS? I'm running the server side localy.